# Password protect entire Joomla site before launch with a temporary login page

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to find a way to password protect an entire Joomla site before going live the with site, with a temporary login page. I cannot do it in Joomla CMS for various reasons.

So I'm trying to find a way in .htaccess or in Apache `/etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com.conf`

I have root access to server.

Right now I use `AuthUserFile` and would like to remove this and go semi-live. Joomla runs from index.php and my PHP temporary login page runs from index2.php. I will change Apache configuration file to look for index2.php as first file.

index2.php:

```
<?php
$msg = '' ;
if (isset($_POST['Submit']) && !empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {

if ($_POST['username'] == 'myusername' && $_POST['password'] == 'mypassword') {

    $_SESSION['valid'] = true;
    $_SESSION['timeout'] = time();
    $_SESSION['username'] = 'myusername';       
    //echo 'You have entered valid use name and password';
    header('Location: https://example.com/index.php');
} else {
    $msg = '<p style="color:#212529;">Wrong username or password.</p>';
}
}?>
```

How can I restrict access to the entire Joomla site if `$_SESSION['valid'] = true;` is not valid set?
Is this even possible?

I'm not looking for a super secure way. It's is just a login page for pre-access users before going live. A way for them to get in and look at my site.

Best regards,
Henrik

Comment: Doesn't joomla already have the maintenance mode? I though it does

Comment: Yes, it does. But for various reasons I cannot use this mode. When Joomla is set to Offline, you get a login page. I you have a valid user, that is allowed to login during Offline mode, then this user will get logged in as something. Guest, Registered, Super User, etc. and then I cannot achieve the user to use my signup form, as the user will already be logged in as something. I would like the user to meet Joomla as Public Guest, but only if the user pass my login script in index2.php.

Comment: Makes sense. But in this case temporarily changing the joomla script to match only the super user would be easier, than writing your custom solution. I.e. condition "if user exists and group is super user". Wouldn't you agree?

Comment: if the user has session valid = true , he should get in normally , if not he has to be redirect to another page right , why not going back to index2 again ?

Comment: @MohammedElhag but how do I do that? How can I protect index.php and rest of joomla, if the user sessions is not validated = true. That's what I'm trying to find a way to. E.g. user could just write URL manually to `example.com/index.php` then he would see Joomla. Or `example.com/an-other-seo-freindly-url/`

Comment: @Henrik see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will give a temporary solution :

**Use cookies** , so when the user in this stage :

```
if ($_POST['username'] == 'myusername' && $_POST['password'] == 'mypassword') {

$_SESSION['valid'] = true;
$_SESSION['timeout'] = time();
$_SESSION['username'] = 'myusername';       
//echo 'You have entered valid use name and password';
header('Location: https://example.com/index.php');
```

Before `$_SESSION['valid'] = true;` put this :

```
setcookie("user", "pass");
setcookie("user", "pass", time()+3600);
```

It is only for one day , then replace this :

`$msg = '<p style="color:#212529;">Wrong username or password.</p>';`

With this :

```
$msg = '<p style="color:#212529;">Please Login</p>';
```

The line above is suggestion to give good user experience even for few days .

Go to `.htaccess` in main root and put this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !user=pass [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index2.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://yourwebsite/index2.php [R=302,L]
```

Keep `R=302` as it is , it says it is temporary redirection and that what you need .

So , right now , no one will be able to explore a website unless passing `index2.php` check.

**Note:** clear browser cache then test.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a the way to go!

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !user=pass [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(?:css|jpg|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/index2.php [R=302,L]
```

In Joomla default `.htaccess` there is a lot of stuff, but right after `RewriteEngine On` I added this and inclueded `css|jpg|png` to get my page looking nice. Below that I left all the other Joomla stuff. What do you think about that?